I am encountering a memory leak issue when using the FlannMatcher and BFMatcher functions in C++ OpenCV
"The specific function code is as follows. When processing two image frames, I call this function in blocks of 128x128 pixels to compute their feature points and match them. However, when I do this, I notice that my memory usage keeps increasing. When I disable the matching function, memory usage returns to normal. Therefore, I believe the issue lies within the matching function.
int API_Similar_Sift(void* handle, int x, int y, int blockSizeX, int blockSizeY, int *num1, int *num2, int *matchNum) {
    int result = 0;
    SimilarSiftHandle* h = static_cast<SimilarSiftHandle*>(handle);
    cv::Rect blockRect(x, y, blockSizeX, blockSizeY);
    if (blockRect.x + blockRect.width > h->img1.cols || blockRect.y + blockRect.height > h->img1.rows) {
        return -1; 
    }

    cv::Mat block1 = h->img1(blockRect);
    cv::Mat block2 = h->img2(blockRect);

    h->kp1.clear();
    h->kp2.clear();
    h->des1.release(); 
    h->des2.release(); 

    h->kp1.reserve(h->maxKeypoints);
    h->kp2.reserve(h->maxKeypoints);
    
    h->akaze->detectAndCompute(block1, cv::noArray(), h->kp1, h->des1);
    h->akaze->detectAndCompute(block2, cv::noArray(), h->kp2, h->des2);
    
    if (!h->kp1.empty() && !h->kp2.empty())
    {
        h->matches.clear(); 
        if (h->des1.type() == CV_8U) {
            h->des1.convertTo(h->des1, CV_32F);
        }
        if (h->des2.type() == CV_8U) {
            h->des2.convertTo(h->des2, CV_32F);
        }
        cv::flann::IndexParams indexParams; 
        cv::FlannBasedMatcher flannMatcher; 
        flannMatcher.match(h->des1, h->des2, h->matches); 
        flannMatcher.clear();

        *num1 = h->kp1.size();
        *num2 = h->kp2.size();
        *matchNum = h->matches.size();
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *num1 = h->kp1.size();
        *num2 = h->kp2.size();
        *matchNum = 0;
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}

I have tried cleaning up all areas where a memory leak might occur, including releasing the memory used for storing feature points and matching results, but the issue remains unresolved. And it is certain that if I don't use these matching functions, the memory leak does not occur. I have tried updating the OpenCV version, but the issue still persists.

Have you tried using any tools to confirm a leak ? Like the GNU Address Sanitizer ? Unless someone knows the specific APIs there is nothing "debuggable" in the code shown because there are no memory allocations or deletes.

Thank you for your suggestion. I tried several of the detection tools you mentioned, but none reported any memory leaks, although memory usage continues to rise. I suspect that the matching function internally allocates memory but does not release it properly after use. Could this be platform-related? I am currently running it on Ubuntu 18.04.

You may not even have a leak. In general as Unix/Linux use more memory the memory usages goes up. As the memory is freed that memory is not actually "released" from the process. This means as your process does more work it may keep getting bigger. Unless this is causing you an issue (like it gets too big) then there is probably nothing to worry about.

you should quantify your statement that memory consumption rises. how much exactly (in MB at least), how does it evolve over time? can you make a plot of that? -- can you run your code such that it produces memory growth of one gigabyte? three gigabytes? ten gigabytes? that is the characteristic of a true leak, it can grow without bounds.

"When I disable the matching function, memory usage returns to normal. Therefore, I believe the issue lies within the matching function." -- Keep going. Comment out about half of the matching function and retest (adding a return 0; or similar if needed). If the memory usage returns to normal, comment out the other half. Binary search down to a particular line.
